# Reading and plotting of svg files in python

Tags: python, svg, graph, plotly, networkx

I have a series of SVG files that I would like to read by Python code, get its coordinates and edges, and plot them again.

For this purpose, I have prepared the following code

```
import svgpathtools
from svg.path import parse_path
from svg.path.path import Line

import networkx as nx

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as ml
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import plotly.graph_objects as go

G = nx.Graph()

fname="output.svg"
paths, attributes = svgpathtools.svg2paths(fname)


ii=0
for path,attr in zip(paths, attributes):
    for e in path:
        x0 = e.start.real
        y0 = e.start.imag
        x1 = e.end.real
        y1 = e.end.imag
        
        
        G.add_node(ii)
        G.nodes[ii]['pos'] = np.array([x0,y0])
        G.add_node(ii+1)
        G.nodes[ii+1]['pos'] = np.array([x1,y1])
        G.add_edge(ii, ii+1)
        
        ii+=2


edge_x = []
edge_y = []
ii=0
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[ii]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[ii+1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    # edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    # edge_y.append(None)
    ii+2


edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

node_x = []
node_y = []
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=10,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line_width=2))

     
fig.show()
```

And I have tested it using an SVG file generated [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecsk/hat/app.html) (after removing supertiles).
The output looks like[image]. The reported graph is clearly different from what I have saved as my SVG file. Do you have any suggestions to improve my code?

**Update I:** I have now removed duplicated nodes and edges from the previous code using

```
import svgpathtools
from svg.path import parse_path
from svg.path.path import Line

import networkx as nx

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as ml
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import plotly.graph_objects as go


Gred = nx.Graph()


fname="output.svg"
paths, attributes = svgpathtools.svg2paths(fname)


ii=0
allpointstart=[]
allpointend=[]
pos={}
for path,attr in zip(paths, attributes):
    for e in path:
        x0 = e.start.real
        y0 = e.start.imag
        x1 = e.end.real
        y1 = e.end.imag
        
        pos.update({ii: (x0,y0)} )
        pos.update({ii+1: (x1,y1)} )
        
        ii+=2
        
posred = {}
ii=0
for key,value in pos.items():
    if value not in posred.values():
        posred[ii] = value
        ii+=1
        
for edge in G.edges():
    
    idx1=idx2=-1
    kk=jj=0
    for key, value in posred.items():
        if value==pos[edge[0]]:
            idx1=key
            jj=1
        if value==pos[edge[1]]:
            idx2=key
            kk=1
        if jj*kk==1: 
            Gred.add_edges_from([(idx1,idx2)])
            break
                
nx.draw_networkx(Gred, pos=posred)
```

The output looks the same and still does not match the original SVG figure.

**Update II:** Using my first code on [this SVG file](https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/19331/line-chart) gives a more reasonable outcome which looks like
[image]